# Background color for nested divs

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for a child div to not inherit the background color of the parent div and instead inherit the background of the body tag?

Eg:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sub">
       some content
     </div>
  </div>
</body>

body {
  background-image: url("blah");
}
#main {
  background-color: white;
}
```

The div sub would always inherit the background-color as white. But is there a way(work around) in CSS to specify that sub should not inherit the white color?? I read that CSS doesn't allow this but is there any work around for this?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to accomplish graphycally. Maybe there is an obvious solution. I think you want something like background image, with a div with white borders, and inside it a "transparent" div with the previous background image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is that there is a background image on the body, the body contains a div that has a white background color.

And then you want a div within this div that sees through to the background image? This is not possible.

There is a way to achieve what you want though, theoretically you could give the 'see-through' div the same background image as the body, and then through reading the coordinates with jQuery (or if the div is always in the same spot you could do it with css) you could position this background image so it overlaps with the body's image. This way it will look as if the inner div acts as a sort of window, achieving the effect you are looking for.

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aFpAX/

**jQuery method**

You can get the window div's coordinates by using `position()`, and then set `background-position` with these values:

```
$(function(){

    var pos = $('#window').position();
    $('#window').css('background-position','-'+pos.left+'px -'+pos.top+'px');

});
```

You can see this in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aFpAX/2/

Comment: Nice solution!But what if there is some content immediately after <div id="main">? If the height of this div is variable, I will not be able to fix the position of background. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If the height of the div is variable, you will have to use jQuery. By using `position()` you can find how the 'window' is positioned relative to the body and then use these coordinates to position the background image.

Comment: Thanks! But strange that CSS doesn't provide this flexibility of not inheriting the property.

Comment: Ive added the jQuery method to my answer, if I solved your problem please vote the answer up and accept it :)

Comment: Done :) thnx for speedy reply

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible anyhow, neither with CSS nor with JS also

Comment: not possible but there could be any kind of hack/solution. The way newbie_python is asking is never possible but it could be possible in different way like Kokos responded.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are using `main` for is to create a border — i.e. there is no other content in it other than `sub` — then perhaps you could use `border` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Or... Use PNG background images, with specific areas made "transparent".

Just remember to set the divs that you want to see through to background:transparent in css.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could consider using css variables in your stylesheet, as follows..

```
@variables {
    bodyColor: #999;
    divColor: #DDD;
}

body {  
    background-color: var(bodyColor);  
}  
#outerDiv {  
    background-color: var(divColor); 
} 
#innerDiv {  
    background-color: var(bodyColor);
}
```

Comment: I have used this only for `background-color` but it can be applied to any other property in the same way.